# Is there a way to convert a CGAL Ellipse into a Polygon_2?

Tags: polygon, computational-geometry, cgal, ellipse

I am using the class CGAL::Min_ellipse_2 to obtain the ellipse of the smallest area enclosing a finite set of points in R² (Euclidean space). Actually, the code is very, very similar to the example provided at https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Bounding_volumes/classCGAL_1_1Min__ellipse__2.html. However, I would like to manipulate the resulting ellipse, which contains a support points set belonging to the boundary of the ellipse, as a polygon object.

This leads to the question: how could I transform a minimum ellipse (class **Min_ellipse_2**) into a polygon (class **Polygon_2**) using CGAL (or other possible approaches)?